# how to have navbar convert to pulldown automatically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

IF you resize your browser to be as small as a phone display on this website http://buffalosw.com, you will notice that the navigation bar becomes a pulldown menu.  Is there a way to have twitter bootstrap automatically do this for me as well?

Also, it would be nice if side navigation bars did the same thing too?

or maybe there is some twitter bootstrap third party component on top of bootstrap that can handle something like this?  (we are just trying to get the web site looking good on a phone is all without too much work).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap already does that. See the navigation menu on the responsive demo page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Comment: that is the grid, not a navbar to pulldown conversation.  I found the answer finally buried in the navbar stuff.

Comment: The black navigation bar at the top of that page does what you asked for. You didn't specify a particular type of navbar in your question.

Comment: ah, that wasn't clear from your post especially since your link had #fluidGridSystem in it like it was the fluid grid.  thanks!  marked your answer as correct then(though you should modify your answer to specify the navbar at the top of the page).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer.  On this page

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

just search for "Response navbar"  It was buried at the bottom of navbar information.

Dean